# How to properly create a Typescript NPM package with declarations?

Tags: typescript, npm

I feel like I'm losing my mind over something that should be very simple.

I have some TypeScript files that contain code I'd like to export for an npm package. To facilitate auto-imports from npm packages, the types of all functions/constants etc. have to be specified in index.d.ts (if I understand correctly).

So my question is, if I have multiple different .ts files each with their own functions/constants, how do I create a single .d.ts file that contains the types for all of the functions/constants in all of the files? Without this, I have to manually import the package; with most other libraries, I can just type a function name, for example, and an import will be suggested.

Comment: Can you post an example minimal repro  library (it doesn't need to include real code, it can be dummy code)  as a github? It should be pretty straight forward - the .d.ts files should be included in the bundled packaged that is uploaded to npm.

Comment: @dwjohnston I've just used npm link so far, I'm testing the package in another project on my system. The only way to import it is by actually typing the import -- if I type the name of a function (that's not in index.d.ts but in one of the other files' d.t.s) then I get no auto-import

Answer (score -1):

We have a few private npm modules we share between node microservices. Recently upgraded them to TS.

I may be way wrong on the why here but this worked for us. The "global.d.ts" files are not included in the compiled file as it is just a reference.

We just created a types folder with an index.ts, put our types in there and imported them into the needed files. Types then get included in the compiled index.d.ts file.

Everything works fine when the package is installed into other TS projects. Was hammering my head on the wall for a whole day too.